# Google App Developer: Change Default Language of App

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I just published my first application on Google Play and I accidentally chose the wrong language as default language for my application. I set "German", though my app is actually in English.

I can't find the settings anywhere where I could possibly change this setting.

Does anyone know where to edit this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

click "add translation", select US English.

This shows another button "manage translations", and you can change the default language, or delete other translations.

Comment: On which page exactly? I can't find such a button.

Comment: oooh, okay, wait. I found it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister where is it?

Comment: @TinMan Under Main Store Listing, top of the body.

Answer (score 15):

Go to **Google Play Console > Store presence > Store listing**.

Click **Manage translations** button, then **Add your own translation text** and select **English (United States) - EN-US** from the list.

Once you have two different languages set for your app, click again on **Manage translations** and choose **Select default language**, going for the right one this time.

If you want to remove the previous language, select **Manage translations** and then **Remove translations**.