# Changing the default language in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Writing words in strings.xml triggers autocorrect, which is set to en-us per default. I use a different language for default, and en-us only as translation. How can I change these default languages in android-studio?

(Searching for this only shows
[Google App Developer: Change Default Language of App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24872407/6123162)
which is limited to Google Play where everything is straight forward.)

Edit: Android-Studio seems to have multiple different hidden language settings, one being the dictionary, but there is also some Default Locale I wasn't able to change. See there picture (en-us to be changed).

[image]

It seems to be disconnected from dictionary, but when I open the Translation Editor it gets renamed to only 'Default' with no options to change.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Preferences menu` -> `Editor` -> `Spelling`:

You can add a custom dictionary.
Your `language.dic` file should contains a UTF-8 charset.

[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for your Input towards the dictionary. I have updated the question towards the 'Default' Language on another occasion, which i though initially to also change the dictionary. It seems the dictionary has nothing to do with it and it is still set to en-us

Comment: This menu changes the strings.xml file used in the preview.

Comment: exactly, however i have only one additional named in 'res/values-en/strings.xml', the Default one is in 'res/vaues/strings.xml'. The question is, why is the Default still associated with en-us? There must be a way to change that.