# How can I set the default language for app in the android studio editor?

Tags: android, configuration, locale

I am trying to change the default language in "Design" mode in android studio and I am unable to find the way to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6d28.png)
The only thing I want is that, when I choose default language, this be spanish.

I have been searching for an answer and I did not find any.

Thanks in advance.

I have been looking for within Android Studio UI

Comment: Try looking at [Changing the default language in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374049/changing-the-default-language-in-android-studio).

Comment: No. I have already read it. It only talks about dictionary which is not the issue. Thank you.